# Preventing IOException (broken pipe) when a process terminates in a chained processes

Tags: java

This following code throws a `IOException: Broken pipe`,
since the `head -c 100` process terminates when it received 100 bytes.

Can I prevent the broken pipe issue?
I would like to gracefully terminate other processes when `head` is finished.
(I know using `ProcessBuilder.startPipeline` just works but I want to explore this method)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process pa = new ProcessBuilder("cat", "/dev/random").start();
        Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("base64", "-w", "0").start();
        Process pc = new ProcessBuilder("head", "-c", "100").start();

        Thread ta = new Thread(uncheck(() -> pa.getInputStream().transferTo(pb.getOutputStream())));
        Thread tb = new Thread(uncheck(() -> pb.getInputStream().transferTo(pc.getOutputStream())));
        Thread tc = new Thread(uncheck(() -> pc.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out)));

        ta.start();
        tb.start();
        tc.start();
        ta.join();
        tb.join();
        tc.join();
    }

    public static Runnable uncheck(Callable<?> runnable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                runnable.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1pbx+pn/KC1F5ckABku6jZCFvfJrKVNJfWCcuLCnkiI1ZpuFj5OzY4BAodycgeDHui8SD+7pcHFf0i9qRe1/Ye63Wd+fF+iX2BK4Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at main.Main.lambda$3(Main.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:783)
    at main.Main.lambda$1(Main.java:13)
    at main.Main.lambda$3(Main.java:27)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Close the output stream before you exit the thread.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that transferTo, and all code, has no way to know when an OutputStream has reached EOF.  I don't know enough about kernels to know how they handle a pipe;  perhaps the sending process’s stdout gets routed to the equivalent of a [nullOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#nullOutputStream()) once the receiving process’s stdin is closed.